# App_Browsers ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using Mobile Device Browser File ( http://mdbf.codeplex.com/ ) for my ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

Locally, with VS 2010 web server, everything works fine : I use Firefox with User Agent Switcher, and it is detected as a mobile device.

However, when I upload the application to my hosting provider, it isn't working anymore.

As it is a shared hosting provider, I can't do many things to "debug"...

Anyone knows if there is special permissions to put on the App_Browsers folder, or anything I could test ?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: .. you might accept the answer given below. It helped my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems if you delete the App_Browsers.dll file the issue resolves it's self.

See: http://www.5limes.com.au/blog/index.php/vs-2010-web-publishing-issue-with-the-browser-files.html